# Changes in JAR file not working

Tags: class, jar

I have been working on a code which access the class file in Jar.

I need the code to print output in a different format. So made the changes in the Tagger.java file and build the Tagger.class file for it.
Then i unzipped the jar file and replaced Tagger.class with the one i updated.
I updated the library, built path.

Now the code which use to work earlier, doesnt work anymore and where the class is called it prompts an error as: **Tagger can not be resolved to a type**

I dont understand where i am going wrong.

Please kindly help.
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you correctly replaced your old class by the new one?

Comment: Are you sure that no exception occured before and that your exception (Tagger can not be resolved to a type) has no cause?